# Combine Pandas data frame column values into new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with Pandas and I have a data frame where we can have one of three values populated:

```
ID_1    ID_2    ID_3
abc     NaN     NaN
NaN     def     NaN
NaN     NaN     ghi
NaN     NaN     jkl
NaN     mno     NaN
pqr     NaN     NaN
```

And my goal is to combine these three columns into a new columns in my data frame:

```
ID_1    ID_2    ID_3  Combined_ID
abc     NaN     NaN    abc
NaN     def     NaN    def
NaN     NaN     ghi    ghi
NaN     NaN     jkl    jkl
NaN     mno     NaN    mno
pqr     NaN     NaN    pqr
```

Ideally it would just find whatever not null value exists in columns 1 through 3, but I could also concatenate since we should only have one of the three populated for each row. Thanks.

```
df_note = pd.read_csv("NoteIds.csv")
df_note['Combined_ID'] = # ID_1 + ID_2 + ID_3
```

Comment: Are we certain that there's only one non-NaN value per row?

Comment: @EdChum - There are actually other columns as well. So yes, only one non NaN but only for those 3 columns, not the entire row.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the property that summing will concatenate the string values, so you could call [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) and pass an empty str and the call [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) and pass param `axis=1` to sum row-wise:

```
In [26]:

df['Combined_ID'] = df.fillna('').sum(axis=1)
df
Out[26]:
  ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 Combined_ID
0  abc  NaN  NaN         abc
1  NaN  def  NaN         def
2  NaN  NaN  ghi         ghi
3  NaN  NaN  jkl         jkl
4  NaN  mno  NaN         mno
5  pqr  NaN  NaN         pqr
```

If you're only interested in those 3 columns you can just select them:

```
In [39]:

df['Combined_ID'] = df[['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3']].fillna('').sum(axis=1)
df
Out[39]:
  ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 Combined_ID
0  abc  NaN  NaN         abc
1  NaN  def  NaN         def
2  NaN  NaN  ghi         ghi
3  NaN  NaN  jkl         jkl
4  NaN  mno  NaN         mno
5  pqr  NaN  NaN         pqr
```

Comment: `df.max(axis=1)` would do without needing `fillna` I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that there can be more than one non-NaN value per row. Still this should work.

```
In [43]: df['Combined_ID'] = df.apply(
                lambda x : ''.join([e for e in x if isinstance(e, basestring)]),
                      axis=1)
```

For each row, extract string items and join them.

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]:
  ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 Combined_ID
0  abc  NaN  NaN         abc
1  NaN  def  NaN         def
2  NaN  NaN  ghi         ghi
3  NaN  NaN  jkl         jkl
4  NaN  mno  NaN         mno
5  pqr  NaN  NaN         pqr
```

I liked @EdChum's answer and looks more readable.

Interestingly, `fillna('').sum(axis=1)` method is expensive for this smaller data.

```
In [45]: %timeit df.fillna('').sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 808 µs per loop

In [46]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x : ''.join([e for e in x if isinstance(e, basestring)]), axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 285 µs per loop
```

For, `['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3']` columns only

```
df[['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3']].apply(lambda_function)
```

Comment: That is not so surprising but `apply` does not scale well, I just did timings on a 600 row df and the timings were 6.24ms vs 33.3ms comparing my method against yours, I expect the performance difference to increase significantly on much larger datasets

Comment: Is there a way to specify only the 3 columns I need? This is getting the other non-related columns included.

Comment: @EdChum Absolutely, `apply` doesn't perform well on larger datasets. So, I mentioned *expensive for this smaller data.* =)

Comment: A faster way might be to `.ffill()` or `.bfill()` along the rows, and take the last / first row's value. That'd handle multiple non-NaN values reasonably fast.

Comment: @SAnand like `df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
df['Combined_ID'] = df.ID_1.fillna('') + df.ID_2.fillna('') + df.ID_3.fillna('')
```

Output:

```
  ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 Combined_ID
0  abc  NaN  NaN         abc
1  NaN  def  NaN         def
2  NaN  NaN  ghi         ghi
3  NaN  NaN  jkl         jkl
4  NaN  mno  NaN         mno
5  pqr  NaN  NaN         pqr
```