# Pandas notnull is not working on column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

A follow-up question from 
[Combine Pandas data frame column values into new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782898/combine-pandas-data-frame-column-values-into-new-column)

I have successfully combined a series of ID's into one field and now I need to filter out any rows that did not end up with a Combined ID value. Usually I would use notnull but on this column it is not working. Can anyone fill me in on the problem? Thanks!

```
df_merged['Combined_ID']  = df_merged[['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5']].apply(lambda x : ''.join([e for e in x if isinstance(e, basestring)]), axis=1)

#Remove any rows that do not have an ID in the new field
#This is not removing the rows that do not have a combined ID value
df_merged = df_merged[pd.notnull(df_merged['Combined_ID'])]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the missing row values really are null? your code should've worked but series have a `notnull()` method available, could you try: `df_merged = df_merged[df_merged['Combined_ID'].notnull()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This column is never going to be null. If every item in the row is *not* a basestring then the function returns `''`.

Therefore the following should work:

```
df_merged = df_merged[df_merged['Combined_ID'] != '']
```

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct Andy and Ed, as I was starting to assume. Now I can see that on the output as well (I was writing to a file where it still appeared blank). The != '' works perfectly. Thanks very much!