# Combine pandas column into new column in certain order of preference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is largely a follow up question from this one.

[Combine Pandas data frame column values into new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782898/combine-pandas-data-frame-column-values-into-new-column)

I want to combine certain columns (not all) of a dateframe into a single column and pick which data to use in certain order of preference and ignore rest.

For instance I have this

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['alpha','beta', np.nan, np.nan],
'B':['alpha_1',np.nan, np.nan, 'delta_1'],
'C': [np.nan,'beta_2', 'gamma_2', 'delta_2']})
```

which gives

```
              A        B        C
        0  alpha  alpha_1      NaN
        1   beta      NaN   beta_2
        2    NaN      NaN  gamma_2
        3    NaN  delta_1  delta_2
```

I want to combine them such that it will first prefer value in `column A` and if that is `NaN` or `null`, it will look for value in `column B` and if not finally in `column C`.
so the final output in `Column D` will be like

```
              A        B        C        D
        0  alpha  alpha_1      NaN       alpha
        1   beta      NaN    beta_2      beta
        2    NaN      NaN    gamma_2     gamma_2
        3   NaN     delta_1  delta_2     delta_1
```

I can do `df.fillna('').sum(axis=1)` as suggested in the solution but I am thinking before that I should make sure every row has only `non NaN` value.

I am trying with boolean masking using `isnull()` on each column but not able to progress too far on that. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with `bfill` what is same as [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `method='bfill'`

```
df['D'] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
       A        B        C        D
0  alpha  alpha_1      NaN    alpha
1   beta      NaN   beta_2     beta
2    NaN      NaN  gamma_2  gamma_2
3    NaN  delta_1  delta_2  delta_1

df['D'] = df.fillna(method='bfill',axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
       A        B        C        D
0  alpha  alpha_1      NaN    alpha
1   beta      NaN   beta_2     beta
2    NaN      NaN  gamma_2  gamma_2
3    NaN  delta_1  delta_2  delta_1
```

Another solution with [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) and `apply`:

```
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
print (df)
       A        B        C        D
0  alpha  alpha_1      NaN    alpha
1   beta      NaN   beta_2     beta
2    NaN      NaN  gamma_2  gamma_2
3    NaN  delta_1  delta_2  delta_1
```

Comment: I like this one: `df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]` +1

Comment: Both the solutions are great. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [338]: df['D'] = df.T.bfill().iloc[0]

In [339]: df
Out[339]:
       A        B        C        D
0  alpha  alpha_1      NaN    alpha
1   beta      NaN   beta_2     beta
2    NaN      NaN  gamma_2  gamma_2
3    NaN  delta_1  delta_2  delta_1
```