# how can I merge two dataframes that have same columns but it has different row values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to put together two dataframes that have the same columns and number of rows, but one of them have nan in some rows and the other doesn't.

This example is with 2 DF, but I have to do this with around 50 DF and get all dataframes merged in 1.

DF1:

```
   id   b    c
0  1   15    1
1  2   nan  nan
2  3   2     3
3  4   nan  nan
```

DF2:

```
   id   b    c
0  1   nan  nan
1  2   26    6
2  3   nan  nan
3  4   60    3
```

Desired output:

```
   id   b    c
0  1   15    1
1  2   26    6
2  3   2     3
3  4   60    3
```

Comment: ``df1.combine_first(df2)``

Comment: or `df1.fillna(df2)`

Comment: Thank you @sushanth and anon01, both answers did the trick. I'm trying to understand why both functions worked for this.

Comment: This previous question discusses the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676134/what-is-the-difference-between-combine-first-and-fillna.  Basically, `fillna` only fills existing `na` col/row values, whereas `combine_first` fits missing values and adds additional cols/rows that don't exist in df1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0, 1], columns=[0, 1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, np.nan]], index=[0, 1], columns=[0, 1])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1]], index=[0, 1], columns=[0, 1])
```

Then you can update `df1`

```
for df in [df2, df3]:
    df1.update(df)

print(df1)

     0    1
0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0
```